# C++ circular dependency with header guards and forward declarations

Tags: c++, dependencies, circular-dependency, cyclic

I have a simple `Vec3` classand a simple `xMath` class.

The `xMath` class is supposed to change the `Vec3`. There are just 2 files `Vec3.hpp` and `xMath.hpp` (and I am **not** allowed to create other files).

- both classes are in the same namespace
- there are header guards
- there are includes on both of them
- `xMath` is not recognized
- using forward declarations does not work, tried

Using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

Getting errors:

- error C2027 *use of undefined type 'ns::xMath'Vec3.hpp*

Using the forward declarations, still getting errors:

- error C2653 *Vec3 is not a class or a namespace name*
- error C2027 *use of undefined type 'ns::Vec3'*

Here are the files.

```
//Vec3.hpp
#ifndef VEC3_H
#define VEC3_H

#include "xMath.hpp"

namespace ns
{
    //class xMath; //forward declaration does not work either..

    struct Vec3
    {
    public:

        float x;

        //constructor
        Vec3(float x) { this.x = x; }

        static float Change(Vec3* v)
        {
            v->x = xMath::Change(v);

            return t;
        }

    };
}

#endif
```

```
//xMath.hpp
#ifndef XMATH_H
#define XMATH_H

#include "Vec3.hpp"

namespace ns
{
    //class Vec3; //forward declaration does not work either..

    static class xMath
    {
    public:

        static float Change (Vec3* v)
        {
            return v->x;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: Remove the `#include "Vec3.hpp"`, and move it to the *end* of the `xMath.hpp` file (right before the `#endif`). Then add a `Vec3` forward declaration inside the `ns` namespace. Then change the `xMath::Change` function (which is a really bad name for something that doesn't actually change anything) to only be a declaration. And lastly define (implement) the `xMath::Change` function *after* the inclusion of `Vec3.hpp`.

Comment: "and I am **not** allowed to create other files" what *are* you allowed to change? For example why is `xMath` a class when it only has static methods? Can it just be a nested namespace?

Comment: Ok, I am actually porting the code from another language to avoid creating a wrapper. The purpose of the Change() method is to only depend on Vec3, no need to complicate the example. I could create the classic .cpp and .h pair but I am hoping I can port the code using just either .h or .hpp because the are over 500 files. It would also help by mirroring as much as possible the other files.

Comment: @Homer512 Yes, xMath could just be a nested namespace but I am looking for a general solution because there are other classes which do not have all their methods as static.

Comment: The "porting from another language" thing worries me. Doing direct "translation" seldom works well. It doesn't matter if it's written., spoken or programming languages. Instead write down a detailed description of the behavior of the program you want to "port" or "translate" (if one doesn't exist already, like a design document), then *reimplement* it in the target language, using all the facilities of the target language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those requirements are very strange.  Normally we'd put the implementation in its own file that includes both headers.

We can do something similar within the headers, though:

```
#ifndef XMATH_H
#define XMATH_H

// First the declarations:

namespace ns
{
    class Vec3;

    class xMath
    {
    public:
        static float Change (Vec3* v);
    };
}


// Now the implementation (which would normally be in xMath.cpp):

#include "Vec3.hpp"

float ns::xMath::Change (Vec3* v)
{
    return v->x;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the reason why the forward declarations were failing in the previous example was because `Vec3` was forward-declared as a `class` but declared fully as a `struct`. The forward-declarations need to be consistent with the actual ones.

Error C2027 occurs against code that is accessing members of an class when only forward declaration is available. There are existing questions from [2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827265/error-c2027-and-error-c2227?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C75.6349), [2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964994/error-c2027-use-of-undefined-type-how-to-declare-class?r=SearchResults&s=18%7C49.3690) and [2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843738/visual-studio-error-c2027?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C70.5350).

With a forward declaration, you can instantiate pointers or references to the forward-declared class. You can't instantiate the class itself and you can't access its members.

Like Toby Speight and Paul Sanderson have suggested, the way to have both classes access each others' members is to implement the classes' methods outside of each class. The sequence is forward declarations, class declarations and finally implementations.

Normally, you would have the method implementations in one or two CPP files and those CPP files would include both header files. If you must use headers only, you can put the include statements after the class definitions.

A forward declaration like this does compile:

```
namespace ns
{
    class XMath;

    class Vec3
    {
    public:
        float m_x;

        Vec3(float x)
                : m_x(x)
                {}
```